# Обновление данных в ViewPager

Tags: android, update

Имеется ViewPager и адаптер для него - PagerAdapter. Если программно изменить текст в некотором TextView на некоторой странице ViewPager'а, то на экране никаких изменений не происходит (текст в TextView не меняется).

**MainActivity.java:**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    MyPagerAdapter adapter = new MyPagerAdapter();
    ViewPager myPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    myPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    myPager.setCurrentItem(1);

    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    View todo_view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.todo_page, null, false);
    TextView tv1 = (TextView) todo_view.findViewById(R.id.dateTextView);
    tv1.setText("Тест");

    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
}
```

**MyPagerAdapter.java**

```
public class MyPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 2;
}

public Object instantiateItem(View collection, int position) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) collection.getContext()
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    int resId = 0;
    switch (position) {
    case 0:
        resId = R.layout.notes_page;
        break;
    case 1:
        resId = R.layout.todo_page;
        break;
    }
    View view = inflater.inflate(resId, null);
    ((ViewPager) collection).addView(view, 0);
    return view;
}

public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
    return POSITION_NONE;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(View arg0, int arg1, Object arg2) {
    ((ViewPager) arg0).removeView((View) arg2);
}
@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View arg0, Object arg1) {
    return arg0 == ((View) arg1);
}
@Override
public Parcelable saveState() {
    return null;
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    switch (position) {
    case 0:
        return "Первая страница";
    case 1:
        return "Вторая страница";
    }
    return null;
}
}
```

Буду рад любой помощи в решении данной проблемы :)

Answer (score 2):

попробуйте поменять

```
TextView tv1 = (TextView) todo_view.findViewById(R.id.dateTextView);
```

на

```
TextView tv1 = (TextView) myPager.findViewById(R.id.dateTextView);
```

Comment: Ошибка при запуске приложения.

Comment: значит просто findViewById(R.id.dateTextView);

Answer (score 0):

И где же вы меняете *"текст в некотором TextView на некоторой странице ViewPager'а"*? Я лишь вижу, что после назначения адаптера для ViewPager, вы инфлэйтите новый view, в котором находите TextView и меняете значение. К ViewPager'у этот новый view никакого отношения не имеет.

Comment: Этот TextView находится на некоторой странице ViewPager'а...

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как будет правильно поменять текст в том TextView?

Comment: Нет, не находится. Этот TextView принадлежит **новому** view, полученному при помощи LayoutInflater.inflate. Более того, вы этот view в дальнейшем даже никак не используете. View, представляющие собой страницы ViewPager во возвращаете в MyPagerAdapter.instantiateItem, вот в них и стоит искать этот TextView.

Comment: Спасибо Вам за ответ! Правда мало чего понял, видимо, надо искать еще примеры использования. В интернетах куча мануалов по ViewPager'у, но в них рассматриваются только самые базовые детали, а примера, подобного моему - не нашел. Буду искать дальше.